# SQL error in windows console [IM06][SQLSetConnectAttr][ODBC]

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, sqlsrv, windows-console

I have written the following php code to connect to a localhost database in windows:

```
<?php

    $serverName = "localhost\sqlexpress";

    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"datebase_name", "UID"=>"datebase_user", "PWD"=>"datebase_pass");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $conn ) {
         echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
    }else{
         echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

?>
```

And the console shows me the following error:

[image: Error]

What is the error?

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
  $serverName = "localhost\sqlexpress";
```

to

```
 $serverName = "localhost\\sqlexpress";
```

Comment: Console shows the same error :S Thanks for your answer!!